# My global axis are all wrong and tilted

Tags: animation, transforms, pose-mode, graph-editor, axis

so im animating, and ive realised that when i use move a bone in pose mode along the global z or y axis (using the curve graph or by editing the transform) that the z axis is actually completely different. i think the difficulty arose when i moved something on its local axis, and now all of the data is messed up somehow

i have tried reinstalling to check if it was blender being weird, but it must be something within the project

Comment: the axis that goes from bone's head to tail is the Y axis and not the Z axis, maybe it is what confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

Try tapping the `Z` button twice. You should see the axis line change. One tap* on the `Z` key moves along local axis, the second tap* on the `Z` key glides along the global ("true") axis.

Think of it like in Astronomy with time and *sidereal* time. It's the exact same thing.

Comment: it worked for me by tapping the actual Z axis.